# Installing Visual Studios using Bootcamp Assistant

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I have recently installed Windows 7 on my Mac using Bootcamp Assistant. I have partitioned a decent amount of memory for it. Now I am trying to install Visual Studios 2010 Express on the Windows partition.

Should I be able to install software after booting up in Windows, because that did not work? So I burned a Visual Studios 2010 Express to a DVD on OSX and then booted up Windows, then tried to install from the DVD but that didn't work either.

All I know is that Bootcamp Assistant has something to do with installing extra software on Windows. But I'm not sure how. I have read the Bootcamp Assistant Guide but that is only a guide to installing Windows.

Any searches I do on Google are for using Virtual Box or say that Bootcamp is a good option for this or that, but does not explain how to do it.  In a nutshell can I use Bootcamp Assistant to install Visual Studios? If so, how? If not, what are my other options?

Comment: What is it saying when you're trying to install and failing. After installing windows with bootcamp, it is just a normal windows install running on your mac. Did you install the drivers from the driver disk bootcamp assistant asked you to make?

Comment: Bootcamp is just to set up Windows for running on your Mac. Once you have installed the specialized drivers for the Mac hardware (trackpad, sreen, camera etc; you must do this from Bootcamp Assistant), there should be nothing stopping you from installing Windows software from **within** Windows.

Answer (score 1):

BootCamp Assistant is only for installing the OS, or burning the drivers CD used to help you complete the installation of drivers for your particular hardware.

Once you have a working Windows 7 install, Bootcamp just provides the facility to boot between the two OS, Windows and OS X.

In this case, you have successfully completed the install of Windows 7, but you are having issues installing VS2010.

Whatever the install issues with VS2010 Express are they are unlikely to be related to the fact that Windows is running on a Mac, and more than likely to be install pre-requisites, such as service pack level, etc.

Without further information its unlikely that we would be able to determine what the issue is, or if it is in any way related to being run under Bootcamp.  Have a look to see what the install.log said.